# How can a Qt application be notified that the user's session is ending and provide it with opportunity to save its state before being terminated?

Tags: qt, session, signal

I am writing a Qt application and have run into the following problem: when the user logs out or attempts to shut down the machine, the application is instantly terminated without providing it any chance to save any data. I assume the app needs to listen for some event. I tried listening for the `SIGTERM` signal, but my application was still terminated before it had a chance to respond to the signal.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 3):

I'm starting to use Qt for application development and I have found a "Session Management" chapter in Qt Reference Documentation. I think you can find some interesting.

> A session is a group of running applications, each of which has a particular state. The session is controlled by a service called the session manager. The applications participating in the session are called session clients.
>   [...]
>   Start by reimplementing QApplication::commitData() to enable your application to take part in the graceful logout process.
>   [...]

You can find it [**here**](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/session.html).